# AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.java: Could not secure response: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLElement cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;

Tags: spring, soap, weblogic12c

SOAP Spring Web Service issue
Java 8
weblogic 12.2.

Error in Log

```
AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.java:263 | Could not secure response:
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLElement cannot
be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement; nested exception is
com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLElement cannot be cast to
javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement
org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecuritySecurementException:
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLElement cannot
be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement; nested exception is
com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLElement cannot be cast to
javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement
```

please help

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: we  started  getting this error after migration from Weblogic old version to WebLogic 12 c . we are returning the response data java object to the service and earlier weblogic version it was working fine however in Weblogic 12  c we are getting this error

Answer (score 1):

set below path in setDomainEnv.sh file of weblogic server

JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Djavax.xml.soap.MetaFactory=weblogic.xml.saaj.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl"
export JAVA_OPTIONS